# Drawing a 3D object in a 3D environment, and converting to math

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, linear-programming, gm.general-mathematics, quadratic-programming

So I have been granted a free time and I want to work on a project but first I had to research.

As we know, lines have infinite points, and with lines, we can create infinite shapes. I want to let users use my 3D environment, to create 3D arts and and turn the shape that they made, into a math function(s).

A close example is, desmos graphic calculator which shows the functions's graph but in a 2D environment. What I want to achieve, is basically reverse of that, so people just paint and use premade shapes(like circles and triangles), to create anything they want, and then they get a list of math function(s) that represents the things they drew.

I'm going to write it in JS most likely and

1. I want to know if it's possible
2. Any good references for someone that have done something similar?
3. Suggestions on where to start
4. Anything thay may be helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: Beizer curves; this is exactly how vector graphics work.

Comment: Seems pretty good subject to start with